# html helper generate bad url with index and ext on CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, helper, cakephp-2.3

The problem is simple,

I trying to generate a link with the Html helper with this code:

```
echo $this->Html->link('<span>PDF</span>', array('action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'pdf'));

echo $this->Html->link('<span>PDF</span>', array('action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'pdf', 'full_base' => true));
```

It generates:

```
<a href="/users.pdf" class="action pdf-action"><span>PDF</span></a>
```

So, Cake, by his own decide to not generate the /index in the url if the action is index, and there is no option on documentation to avoid this.

Anyone have any idea what can i do plz?

Thanks in advice.

EDIT:

I try to generate the url with Router and same result:

```
echo $this->Html->link('<span>PDF</span>', Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'pdf'), true), array('class' => 'action pdf-action', 'escape' => false));
```

Comment: what happens when you specify the controller?

Comment: Are you sure this what is being generated? You have <span>PDF</span> and it has <span>CSV</span> - sure this is the right div?

Comment: Sorry, i was doing tests and copy bad generated code, now is good. The full base generated the same link but with entire url, www.xxxx.com/users.pdf

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are pasting us the right code? what you are giving us should be returning index.pdf. What is the name of the controller you are using? Please copy and paste the exact code you are using.

Comment: echo $this->Html->link('<span>PDF</span>', array('action' => $this->request->action, 'ext' => 'pdf'), array('class' => 'action pdf-action', 'escape' => false));

Comment: for debugging purposes try 'action' => 'index' - see if it works as a manually hardcoded thing.

Comment: Are your routes perhaps interfering with the generated link ?

Comment: Baordog, this->request->action is the same as index, and like i told u, i tried many options, dont continue trying to solve the question with usseles answers plz. Savedario, my config/routes only have 2 lines to route gifs and the root of web to 1 controller default, but thx for help, dont check that before and was a good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this code on routes file.

```
Router::connect('/:controller/index', array('action' => 'index'));
```

It basically force to put index in all controllers when the action is index. Next step find how to only force it when have extension.